# Whitespace Regular expression asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a textbox field, and i want to regulate whats typed in.

I dont want users to type more or less then 6-10 characters. here is my regex for limiting the characters ^.{6,10}$ I got this part working, but I also dont want users to type in whitespace(space). Now i am able to detect whitespace from the beginning of the input and ending of the input, but not if the user types in space in middle of the text. see example.

```
" testing" = regulator detects the space in the beginning. regex i use ^[^\s].+[^\s]$
"testing " = regulator detects the space in the end. regex i use here is same as abow
"test ing" = regulator does not detect the space in the middle. tried different regex with no luck.
```

how can i create a regulator which will do all that i require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the problem with your `.` which matches everything

Do this

`^[^\s]{6,10}$`

`[^\s]` matches any character except `space`

---

**OR**

`^\w{6,10}$`

`\w` is similar to `[\da-zA-Z_]`

Answer (score 2):

Some1.Kill.The.DJ answers is great, but for your personnal knowledge, you can also use the following:

```
^\S{6,10}$
```

`\S` matches any characters except `space` the same way `[^\s]` does